# How to update a selectonemenu depending on other one selected value?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, dynamic-content

I've been having a trouble trying to make my `selectOneMenu` content, depend on the value selected on the other. The content from the first one comes from a table in my DataBase and works perfectly, but the second one is supposed to come from another table, but I can't make it work. Here is my `index.html`, where I'm just trying to prove how this works:

---

```
        <h:outputLabel value="Estado" styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="Estado" value="#{beanInscripcion.id_estado}" valueChangeListener="#{beanInscripcion.buscarMunicipios(event)}" >  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Elegir Estado" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{beanInscripcion.estados}"  
                           var="edo" itemLabel="#{edo.nombre_estado}" itemValue="#{edo.id_estado}" />  
            <p:ajax update="Municipio"  listener="#{beanInscripcion.buscarMunicipios(event)}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu> 
        <p:separator /> 
        <h:outputLabel value="Municipio" styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="Municipio" value="municipio">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{beanInscripcion.municipios}"  
                           var="mun" itemLabel="#{mun.nombre_municipio}" itemValue="#{mun.nombre_municipio}" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

---

And here is the section of my Bean where I'm supposed to get the content for the second menu:

---

```
@ManagedBean(name = "beanInscripcion")
@ViewScoped
public class BeanInscripcion implements Serializable {

    static String strURL;
    private List<Estado> estados; 
    private List<Municipio> municipios;
    private int id_estado;
    public BeanInscripcion() throws SQLException{
            estados = new ArrayList<Estado>();
            buscarEstados();
    }

    public void buscarEstados() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM estado");
        result.beforeFirst();
        while (result.next()) {
            Estado estado = new Estado();
            estado.setId_estado(result.getInt("id_estado"));
            estado.setNombre_estado(result.getString("nombre_estado"));
            estados.add(estado);
        }
    }

    public void buscarMunicipios() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id_municipio, nombre_municipio FROM municipio WHERE Estado_id_estado = '" + id_estado + "'");
        result.beforeFirst();
        while (result.next()) {
            Municipio municipio = new Municipio();
            municipio.setId_municipio(result.getInt("id_municipio"));
            municipio.setNombre_municipio(result.getString("nombre_municipio"));
            municipios.add(municipio);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            strURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(strURL, "root", "root");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Estado> getEstados() {
        return estados;
    }

    public void setEstados(List<Estado> estados) {
        this.estados = estados;
    }

    public List<Municipio> getMunicipios() {
        return municipios;
    }

    public void setMunicipios(List<Municipio> municipios) {
        this.municipios = municipios;
    }

    public int getId_estado() {
        return id_estado;
    }

    public void setId_estado(int id_estado) {
        this.id_estado = id_estado;
    }
}
```

---

I've been working on this for hours and still nothing, I'm really in a hurry here, so I'd appreciate if you give me some help here. Thx a lot for your attention :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `value="municipio"` in `<p:selectOneMenu id="Municipio" value="municipio">` means that the value in that dropdown will never change as you've effectively hardcoded the value on that field to always be `municipio` (and even that will fail conversion). The `value` attribute should be bound to a backing bean variable as in

   ```
     <p:selectOneMenu id="Municipio" value="#{beanInscripcion.municipio}" >  
       <f:selectItems value="#{beanInscripcion.municipios}"  
                      var="mun" itemLabel="#{mun.nombre_municipio}" itemValue="#{mun.nombre_municipio}" />  
   </p:selectOneMenu>
   ```

   and in your backing bean, have

   ```
      Municipio municipio;
     //getter and setter
   ```
2. Remove the parameter `event` from `<p:ajax update="Municipio"  listener="#{beanInscripcion.buscarMunicipios(event)}" />`. It should be

   ```
   <p:ajax update="Municipio"  listener="#{beanInscripcion.buscarMunicipios}" />
   ```
3. Remove `valueChangeListener="#{beanInscripcion.buscarMunicipios(event)}"`. It's unnecessary because you already have a `<p:ajax/>` event defined
4. You will eventually run into problems submitting that form because you haven't created a JSF Converter for that `Municipio` custom type. It's mandatory if you're using anything other than `String` types in your select components. See a short intro to converters/converting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13189326/1530938)

Answer (score 6):

I am using Primefaces and this is pretty simple. I have 2 seleceOneMenus, one for subjects (the parent one) and another one for Topics (the child one.).

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="subject" value="#{QuestionsMB.selectedSubjectId}" var="selectedSubject">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Subject" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{SubjectsMB.subjectsList}" var="selectedSubject" itemValue="#{selectedSubject.id}" itemLabel="#{selectedSubject.subjectName}" />
                <p:ajax update="topic" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>


            <h:selectOneMenu id="topic" value="#{QuestionsMB.selectedTopicId}" var="selectedTopic">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Topic" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{TopicsMB.getTopicsListBySubjectId(QuestionsMB.selectedSubjectId)}" var="selectedTopic" itemValue="#{selectedTopic.id}" itemLabel="#{selectedTopic.topicName}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Just notice, that when subject selectonemenu changes, then the topics menu change according to subject ID. I had create a simple function inside Topics Managed Bean (the managed bean for the child selectonemenu ) by editing the hibernate getList() function like as under:

```
public List<Topics> getTopicsListBySubjectId(String subjectID) 
    {
        Topics topic = new Topics();
        List<Topics> TopicsList = new ArrayList<Topics>();

        if(subjectID.length() != 0)
        {
            topic.setSubjectId(Integer.parseInt(subjectID));
            TopicsList = getTopicsService().getTopicsBySubjectId(topic);
        }
        else
        {   
            TopicsList.addAll(getTopicsService().getTopics());
        }
        return TopicsList;
    }
```

and things worked like a charm.... :)

Answer (score 0):

I know a solution for RichFaces, I'm pretty sure it will works for PrimeFaces as components are almost the same :

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=ajax&sample=selectsUpdates&skin=blueSky

EDIT : Here is the translation applied to your code :

```
<h:outputLabel value="Estado" styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
<p:selectOneMenu id="Estado" value="#{beanInscripcion.id_estado}" valueChangeListener="#{beanInscripcion.buscarMunicipios(event)}" >  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Elegir Estado" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{beanInscripcion.estados}" var="edo" itemLabel="#{edo.nombre_estado}" itemValue="#{edo.id_estado}" />  
    <p:ajax update="second" process="@this" listener="#{beanInscripcion.buscarMunicipios(event)}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:separator />
<p:outputPanel id="second">
    <h:outputLabel rendered="#{not empty beanInscripcion.id_estado}" value="Municipio" styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu rendered="#{not empty beanInscripcion.id_estado}" id="Municipio" value="municipio">  
        <f:selectItems value="#{beanInscripcion.municipios}" var="mun" itemLabel="#{mun.nombre_municipio}" itemValue="#{mun.nombre_municipio}" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:outputPanel>
```

And for the bean :

@ManagedBean(name = "beanInscripcion")
@RequestScoped
public class BeanInscripcion implements Serializable {

```
static String strURL;
private List<Estado> estados; 
private List<Municipio> municipios;
private int id_estado;
public BeanInscripcion() throws SQLException{
        estados = new ArrayList<Estado>();
        buscarEstados();
}

public void buscarEstados() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = getConnection();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM estado");
    result.beforeFirst();
    while (result.next()) {
        Estado estado = new Estado();
        estado.setId_estado(result.getInt("id_estado"));
        estado.setNombre_estado(result.getString("nombre_estado"));
        estados.add(estado);
    }
}

public void buscarMunicipios() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = getConnection();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id_municipio, nombre_municipio FROM municipio WHERE Estado_id_estado = '" + id_estado + "'");
    result.beforeFirst();
    while (result.next()) {
        Municipio municipio = new Municipio();
        municipio.setId_municipio(result.getInt("id_municipio"));
        municipio.setNombre_municipio(result.getString("nombre_municipio"));
        municipios.add(municipio);
    }
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        strURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(strURL, "root", "root");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public List<Estado> getEstados() {
    return estados;
}

public void setEstados(List<Estado> estados) {
    this.estados = estados;
}

public List<Municipio> getMunicipios() {
    return municipios;
}

public void setMunicipios(List<Municipio> municipios) {
    this.municipios = municipios;
}

public int getId_estado() {
    return id_estado;
}

public void setId_estado(int id_estado) {
    this.id_estado = id_estado;
}
```

}

Hope it will work since it is not tested!

Comment: ok, i just tried that, but wont work since i dont have the same properties in primefaces elements, my <p:ajax> tag doesnt have a "render" property or an "execute" one, so i cant use this, but i really apreciate your help, its better than nothing :P

Comment: The PrimeFaces equivalent for render is update, the equivalent of execute is process. Actually RichFaces follow more JSF standards ie f:ajax.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your solution for the OP. You just gave him a link

Answer (score 0):

It is just example. Try to reference for your program.

example.xhtml

```
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{SelectOneMenuBean.selectedValue}" 
                         style="width:195px;" required="true" id="countryMenu">
            <p:ajax update="cityMenu"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{SelectOneMenuBean.countries}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:selectOneMenu style="width:195px;" required="true" id="cityMenu">
            <f:selectItems value="#{SelectOneMenuBean.cities}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

SelectOneMenuBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="SelectOneMenuBean")
public class SelectOneMenuBean {
    private String selectedValue;

    public String getSelectedValue() {
        return selectedValue;
    }

    public void setSelectedValue(String selectedValue) {
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
    }

    public String[] getCountries() {
        return new String[] {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"};
    }

    public String[] getCities() {
        if(selectedValue != null && selectedValue.equals("AAA")) {
            return new String[] {"City_1 of AAA", "City_2 of AAA", "City_3 of AAA"};
        } else if(selectedValue != null && selectedValue.equals("BBB")) {
            return new String[] {"City_1 of BBB", "City_2 of BBB", "City_3 of BBB"};
        } else if(selectedValue != null && selectedValue.equals("CCC")) {
            return new String[] {"City_1 of CCC", "City_2 of CCC", "City_3 of CCC"};
        } else if(selectedValue != null && selectedValue.equals("CCC")) {
            return new String[] {"City_1 of CCC", "City_2 of CCC", "City_3 of CCC"};
        } 
        return new String[] {"No City"};
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying your example with my own code modifications and im not pretty sure of what scope to use, which one will you recommend me?

Comment: lol, i got a new problem, i sticked to your example and tried to implement to mine but for some reason the second <selectOneMenu> disappears instead of showing the new content